# "<t> is undefined" error on first keypress

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, gui-emacs

So here's a pretty weird issue. Sometimes, when I start my emacs and press a key combination, the message `<t>` is undefined` gets printed in the echo area, and I need to press the key combo again. I've been trying to track this problem down for a few months now without success.

A bit more info can be found here:

- https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7855
- https://github.com/PythonNut/emacs-config/issues/19

I would be glad to provide more information to aid in debugging.

Comment: It seems to be linked to [Bug#17650](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17650) which is marked as done. So is this fixed now?

Comment: I'm getting this currently in Emacs 25.3.2, every time I alt-tab into Emacs.

Comment: So company-mode used a workaround on sit-for to avoid it https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/760 (so if you use company-mode, better update) – but I've also seen it happen when I had a crontab thing that would run `emacsclient --eval` every so often. I don't know if this one is also fixed in Emacs master by https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23980